# Как программно выполнять команды в CMD

Tags: c, windows, cmd

Как реализовать, чтобы работало в потоке..или как это называется?
Книжки приветствуются..

```
SET STR=QWEQWE;      //команда 1
echo %STR% >> 1.txt; //команда 2
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно...

Comment: если я сделаю так..то переменная в файл не запишется ..нужен поток ввода..
system("SET STR=QWEQWE");
system("echo %STR% >>1.txt");

Comment: Нужно нормально в вопросе написать чего вы хотите добиться. Причем так, чтобы это смогли понять другие.

Comment: Так понятно? Что дальше?

Comment: Вопрос интересный, но, честно говоря, сформулировали вы его не очень, даже после правки сильно лучше не стало :)

Comment: Речь о потоке данных (stream) или о потоке выполнения (thread)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Окей, смотрите. Вот ваш код:

```
system("SET STR=QWEQWE");
system("echo %STR% >>1.txt");
```

Вы собираетесь изменить переменную окружения, и воспользоваться этим в следующем вызове. Проблема в том, что командой `system("SET STR=QWEQWE");` вы меняете значение переменной окружения `STR` лишь в *порождённом* командном интерпретаторе. А следующая команда команда `system("echo %STR% >>1.txt");` выполняется в *новом* порождённом командном интерпретаторе.

---

Например, что-то такое должно подойти:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* tmp_name = _tempnam(NULL, NULL);
    size_t name_len = strlen(tmp_name) + 4 /*.cmd*/ + 1 /*\0*/;
    char* cmd_name = (char*)malloc(name_len);
    sprintf(cmd_name, "%s.cmd", tmp_name);

    FILE* fp = fopen(cmd_name, "wb");
    fprintf(fp, "%s", "set STR=QWE\n");
    fprintf(fp, "%s", "echo %STR% >> 1.txt\n");
    fclose(fp);

    int result = system(cmd_name);

    remove(cmd_name);

    free(cmd_name);
    free(tmp_name);

    return 0;
}
```

Код тестировался на Microsoft Visual Studio, возможно, для других компиляторов понадобится заменить `_tempnam` на что-то другое.

В этом коде вовсе нет проверки на ошибки. Не забудьте проверить возвращаемое значение `_tempnam` (может быть `NULL`), файловых операций, а для `system` также и `errno`.

---

На всякий случай, вариант на C++. На «чистом» C++ я не нашёл возможности создать временное имя файла, пришлось воспользоваться C-style API.

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* tmp_name = _tempnam(NULL, NULL);
    auto cmd_name = std::string(tmp_name) + ".cmd";
    {
        std::ofstream f(cmd_name);
        f << "set STR=QWE\n";
        f << "echo %STR% >> 1.txt\n";
    }
    int result = std::system(cmd_name.c_str());
    std::remove(cmd_name.c_str());
    free(tmp_name);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Если вы используете Microsoft Visual Studio, вам скорее всего понадобится ещё `#include "stdafx.h"` в самом начале.

Comment: Ага) это я примерно понимаю..а как же сделать правильно?

Comment: @Илья `SetEnvironmentVariable` в Windows, https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms686206%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, `setenv` в Linux http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setenv.3.html

Comment: Ага)) все бы хорошо..но у меня программка на СИ(не с++) c++ я не учил.

Comment: @Илья: Обновил, готово.

Comment: Спасибо) что посоветуете почитать по СИ   windows?

Comment: @Илья: Кернигана/Ричи? А вообще, не знаю, я не спец в C. Вот [avp](/users/232/avp) зубр и гигант, если он попадётся вам на сайте, спросите.

Comment: @VladD у вас изначально была реализация на _C++_, мне кажется будет здрово, если оставите оба варианта реализации (на _C_ и на _C++_), так как вопрос может заинтересовать будущих читателей :)